# Does abstract factory introduce tight coupling

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern, abstract-factory

I have a scenario where I think I am not strictly coding to an interface. 
Let's say I have an interface (in some assembly)

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void GetSomething();
    void SaveSomething();
}
```

Now, I have an implementation for this as (in some other assembly)

```
public class FoodB : IFoo
{
   public FoodB(Guid guid, IFoodBConfig config)  //IFoodBConfig is defined in same library where FoodB exists
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

So, basically the implementation requires guid and config

Now, I have a client (in some other assembly) that wishes to use `IFoo`, something like

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(IFoo foo)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

DIP says that the implementation must be provided at composition root and the client must not instantiate the object itself. Alright great.

Now, composition root or IoC container decides to inject `FoodB` as concrete instance but it doesn't have the value for 'guid' since that becomes available during runtime only.

So, we decide on an abstract factory.

```
public abstract FooFactory
{
    public abstract IFoo GetFoo(Guid guid, IFoodBConfig config);
}
```

Now, several questions are raised

a) Client constructor must be modified to accept `FooFactory` and not `IFoo` which means the client has already made up its mind on what implementation to use. In my opinion this has made the software tightly coupled

b) Even if the Client constructor is modified to accept `FooFactory`, `IFoodBConfig` concrete must be supplied to constructor as well and this will now make client reference the library where `FoodB` exists.

c) Where will the factory declaration and implementation be placed ? Putting `FooFactory` in the library where `IFoo` is declared is not correct since the factory has nothing to do with `IFoo`. Putting `FooFactory` in `FoodB` library is also not correct because of the same reason

d) Using abstract factory in short means flexibility of swapping implementation has gone away since client is directory tied to `FoodBFactory`.

Is the approach incorrect or this is some limitation that we have to live with ?

Comment: a) an abstract class cannot be instantiated, it is not an implementation.  You are only coupled to the interface of the abstract class. b) if you want to use something, you do have to reference its library c) the factory creates IFoo, but has nothing to do with IFoo? d) no it is tied to FooFactory, which is abstract

Comment: Does that mean the `FooFactory` should essentially be renamed to public interface `FoodBFactory` to clearly state that it creates `FoodB` types only ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several points to address in this question.

1. `FooFactory` is not an example of an `Abstract Factory`, at least by the GoF terminology.
    `Abstract Factory` != abstract class named Factory.
2. The composition root is not required to have all of its arguments at compile time. Modern IoC containers should all support runtime arguments.

a) As @dbugger commented, coupling the client to an abstract class is no different from coupling to an interface.

b) Either the `FooBFactory` implementation or the IoC container can be pre-configured with `FooBConfig`. The client then only passes its runtime guid.

c) `FooFactory` is directly related to `IFoo` because its purpose is to return an instance of `IFoo`. Indeed, the return type of its method is `IFoo`.

d) Flexibility exists because an IoC container can inject different implementations of a [Factory Method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) into the client, allowing the client to acquire different products without having knowledge of either the product implementation or the factory implementation used to instantiate it.

If you're comfortable coupling the client to the IoC container, the client can use the container directly as a factory, eliminating the additional factory interface.

Comment: Well, first of all the Client only needed `IFoo` instance as dependency. Then the question is why did the factory come into the picture at all ? It was only because Client wanted `FoodB` instance passed to it, it decided that it needed a factory. To me this itself is coupling to an implementation. In the most purest approach the Client must simply advertise the dependency (which is `IFoo`) and let composition root inject them.

Comment: Also, can I now pass a different implementation of `IFoo` to Client ? Of course not. I will have to essentially pass a factory implementation of `FooFactory` and may be that implementation does not require guid or config

Comment: This client doesn't only need an `IFoo`. It needs something which can take a client's guid and return an `IFoo`. If the client didn't need to pass a guid, then it might only need an `IFoo`. Either way, the client's need dictates the nature of the dependency.

Comment: Factory Method is a fine solution to this problem, particularly if the `config` can be moved into the concrete factory so that clients don't have to deal with it.